# Replacing a part of file path and getting the results in Sonarqube

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, sonarqube5.1

I'm trying to write a Powershell script in jenkins to read a file and replace a part of the filepath in that fil. The below script works out when I hardcode the path:

```
$file = "$env:WORKSPACE\UIArtifacts\unit-tests-lcov.info" 
$text = (Get-Content -Path $file -ReadCount 0) -join "`n" 
$text -replace "c:\\Sysapps\\Hudson\\.jenkins\\jobs\\Encirca - UI CI\\workspace\\trunk\\app", $env:WORKSPACE | Set-Content -Path $file
```

But, when I dynamically set the file path I don't get the results. Below is the script I'm trying to run:

```
$file = "$env:WORKSPACE\UIArtifacts\unit-tests-lcov.info" 
$text = (Get-Content -Path $file -ReadCount 0) -join "`n" 
$text -replace ".*\\workspace\\trunk\\app", $env:WORKSPACE | Set-Content -Path $file
```

Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "$env:WORKSPACE\UIArtifacts\unit-tests-lcov.info" 
$text = (Get-Content -Path $file -ReadCount 0) -join "`n"
$replace = ".*\\trunk\\app"
$text -replace $replace $env:WORKSPACE | Set-Content -Path $file

PS C:\Windows\system32> $file = "C:\temp\test.txt"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $text = (Get-Content -Path $file -ReadCount 0) -join "`n" 

PS C:\Windows\system32> $text
c:\Sysapps\Hudson\.jenkins\jobs\Encirca - UI CI\workspace\trunk\app\TestFolder1\TestFolder2

PS C:\Windows\system32> $string = ".*\\trunk\\app"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $text -replace $string, "Set\Custom\Path\Here" | Set-Content -Path $file

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Content $file
Set\Custom\Path\Here\TestFolder1\TestFolder2
```

Comment: The above script executed but I did not get the solution. I'm getting the solution when I'm hardcoding the file path. Any further help?

Comment: Where does the code differ from yours? Is the part of a path youre trying to replace always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes, it is always at the beginning of the path